# slow filling of uint8 data field from python

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found this issue in both ros2 eloquent and foxy. When filling an Image message or a PointCloud2 message from a numpy.array, filling the data field is extremely slow.

For instance, with the point cloud message:

```
cloud_msg = PointCloud2()
cloud_msg.data = cloud_arr.tostring() # cloud_arr is my point cloud as numpy array
```

The tostring() itself is fast, but the assignment to cloud_msg.data is what takes time.
I cannot get the publishing rate over 1 Hz because of how much time is spent in filling the message.

What should I do to publish point clouds in python at a decent rate?

EDIT: I managed to get it a bit faster by setting PYTHONOPTIMIZE to 1. I noticed that the point cloud filling was performing a lot of extra checks if **debug** was set to True. This allows me to get the message filling down from 0.4 seconds to 0.002.
Now the publish() part is the slowest, taking 0.04 seconds. Is there any chance of improving this as well, or is this as fast as it can get?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356660/slow-filling-of-uint8-data-field-from-python/) by [esterina](https://answers.ros.org/users/56486/esterina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To fill the message field you shouldn't convert your `numpy` array to a string and then during the assignment convert the string back into an `array.array` (which is the type of the `data` fields, see http://design.ros2.org/articles/idl_interface_definition.html).

Have you tried to populate the `array.array` directly from the (1 dimensional?) `numpy` array? (Without having run the following code) something like this:

```
cloud_msg.data.frombytes(cloud_arr[0])
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [esterina](https://answers.ros.org/users/56486/esterina/) on 2020-07-09**:
Thanks! That makes it faster, without having to set PYTHONOPTIMIZE to 1!

I still need to use the tostring() method because my array is not an array of bytes, it has N entries each with x, y, z and R,G,B fields, but once I have the bytes calling frombytes() instead of assigning it is much faster.

Since I did not find a built in python function to fill a PointCloud2 message, I adapted the code from this: [link text](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/ros_numpy/html/point__cloud2_8py_source.html). That's where I took the assignment of data instead of using frombytes.